# Generate multiple xml files

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

for testing purposes I need to generate a lot of xml files with dummy data from an xsd file. I know intellij can create xml from xsd file but it only creates one, and if go this way it will take forever. Is there a tool or a library that can do a job like this?

Comment: You could try generating one using IntelliJ (or other tools) and then generating random variations on it using XSLT. But I'm not sure the result will be very effective - what you really need for testing is to include edge cases, extreme values, etc, and random data will never achieve that.

Comment: Using some schema object model walking the schema it should be possible to create samples, for .NET there is a project around in C# source code doing that. I have never come across a sample for Java but would think that the XML editors or IDEs providing such a feature perhaps just integrate some library.

Comment: Using some schema object model walking the schema it should be possible to create samples, for .NET there is a project around in C# source code doing that. I have never come across a sample for Java but would think that the XML editors or IDEs providing such a feature perhaps just integrate some library.

Comment: For C#: https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator/tree/master/XmlSampleGenerator